# how to load all inner objects in entity using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Im using in my project hibernate to load database table into object (entity) with other inner associacions   objects. For example:

class ApplicationEntity:

```
 class ApplicationEntity{

    private RoutesEntity routesEntity;

    private ViewsEntity viewsEntity;

    //....... some other class body

 }
```

class RoutesEntity:

```
 class RoutesEntity{

       private UrlEntity urlEntity;

       private PermissionEntity permmisionEntity;

 }
```

class ViewsEntity:

```
  class ViewsEntity{

        private ContentEntity contentsEntity;

        private LayoutEntity layoutEntity;


  }
```

Now i would like to load completely object ApplicationEntity (with inner objects) using HQL. But avoiding using join fetch i HQL for example:

```
      application = getSession().createQuery("from ApplicationEntity appEntity"
                + " join fetch appEntity.routesEntity rEntity"
                + "  join fetch appEntity.viewsEntity vEntity"
                + "  join fetch rEntity.urlEntity uEntity"
                + "  join fetch rEntity.perrmisioEntity pEntity"
                   etc ......... to get alot of joins
         );
        commit();
```

is possible to use simple

```
     application = getSession().createQuery("from ApplicationEntity");
```

but in lazy mode but working like eager mode

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to load completely object ApplicationEntity (with inner objects) using HQL. But avoiding using join fetch

Comment: That is the default behaviour in hibernate, unless you set the property to be lazily loaded explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First access of property, marked as 'lazy' will fetch it (or throw famous 'No Session or Session was closed' exception). 
So just create function like:

```
public void fetchAll(ApplicationEntity a) {

          a.getRoutesEntity().getUrlEntity();
          ..
          a.getViewsEntity().getLayoutEntity();

}
```

and call it from inside of hibernate session.